# NSLayoutConstraints conflicts

Tags: objective-c, nsview, nslayoutconstraint

I'm trying to add buttons programmatically to a view below an NSTextField that is already in the view. The view was created in IB and uses constraints. It is an NSTableCellView, but I doubt that makes any difference in this case. My code is thus:

```
NSView *previousView = self.pathsField;

for( NSString *path in self.revision.paths )
{
    NSButton *pb = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame: bframe];

    pb.bezelStyle = NSRoundRectBezelStyle;
    [self addSubview: pb];
    pb.title = path;
    [self addConstraint: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: pb
                                           attribute: NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                           relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                           toItem: previousView
                                           attribute: NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                           multiplier: 1 constant: 2.0]];
    [buttons addObject: pb];
    bframe.origin.y += 20;
    previousView = pb;
}
self.pathButtons = buttons;
```

If I take the addConstraint call out the buttons get added with no complaints (just not in the right place). With the addConstraint call I get a lot of messages about constraint conflicts on the debug console and some of my IB created constraints get broken.

Obviously I'm doing something wrong. I expected the constraint to require that the new button's top be 2 px below the bottom of the previous view or button. It doesn't seem like that should cause any conflicts, so where am I off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually making *both* kinds of mistake you can make with constraints: your constraints are *both* conflicted *and* ambiguous! Get rid of the conflict by setting `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to NO, as someone else has said, but then start worrying about the ambiguity. You can use constraints successfully only if you specify *everything* needed for layout. You are specifying the top but that's all; you also need to specify the leading edge (left), and probably the width and height too (maybe not because a button sometimes has an intrinsic size; you will have to experiment).

Comment: Right on! Thanks for the help. The translatesAutoResizingMask was the missing bit. After that it was simple to get layout to behave.

Comment: Be sure to check for ambiguity! The best way is: pause in the debugger, and say `po [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]` in the debugger console's command line.

Answer (score 1):

The errors you are getting are because you have not opted in to autolayout by calling `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:` on the child views.

```
NSButton *pb = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame: bframe];
[pb setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
```